# Как правильно написать полное официальное название школы?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *"окончил комунальную государственную учреждению общеобразовательной средней школы номер 35 имени Б. Гафурова"* или *"окончил общеобразовательную среднюю школу комунальную государственну учреждению номер 35 имени Б. Гафурова"?* По-моему, первый вариант грамматически правильный, но я не уверена.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о порядке слов. Здесь нет и не может быть грамматической правильности. Правильным считается тот вариант, который дан учреждению (предприятию, фирме, юрлицу) в учредительных документах.

Если название дано на иностранном языке и нет аутентичного текста на русском, то воспользуйтесь любым более или менее официальным переводом. Просто переносить порядок определений с одного языка на другой не всегда корректно (в английском, например, и французском принят разный порядок - в зависимости от важности характеристики).

Но - самое главное. Все сказанное - только для официальных текстов. Если вы пишете не слишком официальный текст, не старайтесь приводить полное название вовсе. Это совершенно излишне, только напрягает читающего. Вполне достаточно сокращенного, а то и вовсе "бытового" названия. На последнее правила зафиксированного названия, естественно, не распространяются.

Теперь о ваших вариантах. У вас все падежные окончания перепутаны.

По-русски возможно только следующее.
***Окончил коммунальное государственное учреждение "Общеобразовательная средняя школа номер 35 имени Б. Гафурова"***.
Или, если зафиксирован другой порядок для первых определений,
***Окончил государственное коммунальное учреждение "Общеобразовательная средняя школа номер 35 имени Б. Гафурова"***.

Comment: *Просто переносить порядок определений с одного языка на другой не всегда корректно* - Воистину так. не пришлось работать с документами абитуры из Средней Азии... Господи, чего они там только не понапишут... Но в данном случае можно верить, порядок тот же. Самое важное (государственное) - в начале. "Коммунальное" здесь - ну это примерно то же что поселковая, ну или если совсем точно - "волостная" (аналог сельсоветов).

Answer (score 0):

Я поискала прецеденты - на первом месте слово "государственный". Но возможно, в Казахстане другой порядок слов принят...

***Окончила Государственное коммунальное учреждение "Общеобразовательная средняя школа № 35 имени Б. Гафурова".***

Южно-Казахстанская область, Сарыагашский район?

Тогда, если не по месту жительства даётся информация, после кавычек следует указать область, район, город/посёлок.

Посмотрите [**примеры оформления**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:19FAfaITFP8J:robotics.nis.edu.kz/schools/yuzhno-kazahstanskaya/saryagashskiy/%20&cd=5&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru). Но там ошибки в падежах, как и у Вас...

***Окончила Государственное коммунальное учреждение "Общеобразовательная средняя школа № 35 имени Б. Гафурова", Южно-Казахстанская область, с. Бостандык.***

См. [Государственное учреждение "Общая средняя школа № 35 имени Б. Гафурова"](http://gu-obshchaya-srednyaya-shkola-35-imeni-b-gafurova.s-bostandyk.bizzlist.kz/#s).

"№ 35 Б.Ғафуров атындағы жалпы орта мектебі" мемлекеттік мекемесі" - эта школа?

> Бостандык (каз. Бостандық) — село в Акжарском районе
>   Северо-Казахстанской области Казахстана. Административный центр
>   Кишикараойского сельского округа.